# Category specific internal links from product page to layered navigation pages

Tags: magento2

I am looking for a solution something like what this product page has under the additional info section where the product attributes are linked to category specific layered navigation URLs. How can I achieve this? I really don't find any cross link extension for magento 2 in the market offering this functionality.

For example Color: Green takes you to https://www.utsavfashion.in/salwar/green

https://www.utsavfashion.in/product/embroidered-net-pakistani-suit-in-light-olive-green-kch2160

For example Color: Green takes you to https://www.utsavfashion.in/lehenga/green

https://www.utsavfashion.in/product/embroidered-net-lehenga-in-dusty-green-lcc312